# How to create a Head Up Display radar with Item on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I wrote the question before from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915906/how-to-create-a-head-up-display-radar-on-windows-phone-7).

I managed to create the code by using Canvas and Path as my custom compass as below :-
But how to set my Items (on function CreateRadar) on top of the canvas by using GeoCoordinate? And how to link the relationship with the direction of Compass with this Items?

Below here will be my codes:

**Location.xml**

```
<results>
  <items id="458w281z-e7e923bd28614b33a1f8eb25ba75729d"
         latitude="3.1302" 
         longitude="101.58415" 
         distance="1374" 
         title ="Tropicana Golf &amp; Country Resort" 
         src="Images/tropicana.JPG"
         averageRating="0"
         icon="http://download.vcdn.nokia.com/p/d/places2/icons/categories/01.icon"
         vicinity="Jalan Kelab Tropicana 47810 Petaling Jaya"
         type="urn:nlp-types:place">        
        <category id="hotel" 
                  title="ATMs" 
                  href="http://demo.places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/categories/places/hotel?app_id=7vivA7jIFlZh9WX_B0cd&amp;app_code=6ptUAobtF0RFJ9CkfX7geg" 
                  type="urn:nlp-types:category" />
  </items>
<results>
```

**Page1.xaml**

```
 <radar:EllipsesWithEllipse Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="120" Width="120></radar:EllipsesWithEllipse>
```

**User Control - EllipsesWithEllipse.xaml**

```
<Canvas x:Name="compassHUD" Background="#3F000000" >
        <Canvas x:Name="CompassFace" Height="120" Width="120" Background="#3F000000">
            <Image Source="circle.png" Width="120" Height="120" Opacity="0.5" >
                <Image.Clip>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="120" RadiusY="120" Center="60,60"/>
                </Image.Clip>
            </Image>
            <Canvas x:Name="RadarGrid">
                <Ellipse Fill="Black" Width="10" Height="10"></Ellipse>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
        <Path Stretch="Fill"  Margin="30,-2,0,0" Width="60" Height="65" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#909090" 
              Fill="#909090" Opacity="0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False"  
              Data="F1 M149.55586,154.64513 L228,22.999901 C201,12.1666 174,1.3332601 147.5,2.0832601 C121,2.8332601 95,15.1666 69,27.499901 L149.55586,154.64513 z" />
    </Canvas>
```

**EllipsesWithEllipse.xaml.cs**

```
#region Properties
private PositionHelper pos_helper;
private GeoCoordinate currentLocation;
private List<Place> places;
#endregion

        public EllipsesWithEllipse()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pos_helper = new PositionHelper();
            currentLocation = new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble("3.33312"), Convert.ToDouble("101.6432"));
            CreateRadar(currentLocation);
        }
private void CreateRadar(GeoCoordinate currentPosition)
        {
            //char character;
            places = pos_helper.ParsePlaces(pos_helper.GetPlaces(currentPosition));

            double lon;
            double lat;
            Point point = new Point();

            foreach (Place place in places)
            {
                char ns = lat < 0 ? 'S' : 'N'; //Southern or Northern hemisphere?
        char ew = lon < 0 ? 'W' : 'E'; //Eastern or Western hemisphere?

                lon = Math.Abs(place.position.Longitude);
                lat = Math.Abs(place.position.Latitude);

                //convert lat and lon to y, x
                point =  ToCanvas(place.position.Longitude, place.position.Latitude);


                Ellipse e = new Ellipse();
                e.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                e.Width = 8;
                e.Height = 8;


                RadarGrid.Children.Add(e);

                lon = Math.Abs(point.Y);
                lat = Math.Abs(point.X);

                Canvas.SetLeft(e, lon);
                Canvas.SetTop(e, lat);
            }
        }


        Point ToCanvas(double lat, double lon)
        {
            double x = 120 / 360; //canvas width was fixed
            x *= (lon - -180);
            double y = 120 / 180; //canvas height was fixed
            y *= -(lat + -90);
            return new Point(x, y);
        }
```

**PositionHelper.cs**

```
public static GeoCoordinate CurrentLocation { get; set; }
        public string GetPlaces(GeoCoordinate location)
        {
            CurrentLocation = location;

            Stream xmlfilePath = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("XMLFileCustom.xml", UriKind.Relative)).Stream;

            XElement appDataXml;
            appDataXml = XElement.Load(xmlfilePath);
            try
            {
                // Get a stream to the XML file which contains the data and load it into the XElement. 

            }
            catch { }
            finally
            {
                xmlfilePath.Close();
                xmlfilePath.Dispose();

            }

            return appDataXml.ToString();

        }

        public List<Place> ParsePlaces(string rawxml)
        {
            List<Place> places = new List<Place>();


                places = (from item in XElement.Parse(rawxml).Descendants("items").Elements("category")
                          select new Place()
                          {
                              id = (string)item.Parent.Attribute("id").Value,
                              title = (string)item.Parent.Attribute("title").Value,
                              image = (string)item.Parent.Attribute("src").Value,
                              averageRating = (double.Parse(item.Parent.Attribute("averageRating").Value)),
                              position = new GeoCoordinate(double.Parse(item.Parent.Attribute("latitude").Value), double.Parse(item.Parent.Attribute("longitude").Value), 0),
                              distance = (double.Parse(item.Parent.Attribute("distance").Value)),
                              href = (string)item.Parent.Attribute("href").Value,
                              icon = (string)item.Parent.Attribute("icon").Value,
                              vicinity = (string)item.Parent.Attribute("vicinity").Value,
                              type = (string)item.Parent.Attribute("type").Value,

                              category = new Category()
                              {
                                  href = (string)item.Attribute("href").Value,
                                  id = (string)item.Attribute("id").Value,
                                  title = (string)item.Parent.Attribute("title").Value,
                                  type = (string)item.Attribute("type").Value
                              }

                          }).ToList();

            return places;
        }
}


    [DataContract]
    public class Place
    {
        private GeoCoordinate _position;
        public GeoCoordinate position
        {
            get { return _position; }
            set { _position = value; }
        }

        private double _distance;
        public double distance
        {
            get { return _distance; }
            set { _distance = value; }
        }

        private string _title;
        public string title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; }
        }

        private string _image;
        public string image
        {
            get { return _image; }
            set { _image = value; }
        }

        private double _averageRating;
        public double averageRating
        {
            get { return _averageRating; }
            set { _averageRating = value; }
        }

        private string _icon;
        public string icon
        {
            get { return _icon; }
            set { _icon = value; }
        }



        private string _vicinity;
        public string vicinity
        {
            get { return _vicinity; }
            set { _vicinity = value; }
        }

        private string _type;
        public string type
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set { _type = value; }
        }

        private string _href;
        public string href
        {
            get { return _href; }
            set { _href = value; }
        }

        private string _id;
        public string id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        private string _tag;
        public string tag
        {
            get { return _tag; }
            set { _tag = value; }
        }

        public Category category { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Category
    {
        private string _id;
        public string id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        private string _title;
        public string title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; }
        }

        private string _href;
        public string href
        {
            get { return _href; }
            set { _href = value; }
        }

        private string _type;
        public string type
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set { _type = value; }
        }

    }
```